# Ionic 3 SQLite: SQLiteObject's method executeSql() not working

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-storage

What I have done:

1. Installed ionic today, by the command `npm install -g ionic` and saying 'y' to the cordova integration.
2. Installed cordova: `npm install -g cordova`
3. Created a new project: `ionic start sqlite3demo blank`
4. Installed Ionic native storage:

   `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage`

   `npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite`

Now for the code. I imported `SQLite` into `app.module.ts` like this:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    SQLite
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And then, I modified the default home page like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      SQLite demo
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-content>

    <button ion-button (click)="createTables()">Create db</button>
    <p>Result: {{ message }}</p>

  </ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

And finally, I modified `home.ts` like this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  message = '';
  db: SQLiteObject;

  constructor(private platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, private sqlite: SQLite) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'todos.db',
        location: 'default'
      })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          this.message = JSON.stringify(db);
          this.db = db;
        });
    });
  }

  public createTables() {
    return this.db.executeSql(
      `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name TEXT
      );`)
      .then(() => this.message = 'OK')
      .catch((err) => this.message = "error detected creating tables -> " + JSON.stringify(err));
  }

}
```

After all that, I execute `ionic cordova run android`, and I can see the JSON from `db`, but after that, I click the button to create a table and instead of seeing 'OK', I see the JSON from the error.

[image: Start]

[image: After pressing the button]

What did I do wrong? Why isn't it working?

**EDIT:** The versions I'm using are:

```
"@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.12.2",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.4.0"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, as it's described [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15584), the documentation was obsolete. The way `executeSql()` works is passing a `[]` as second parameter. It seems that Ionic Native team doesn't consider updating their documentation too much. There are other plugins with obsolete documentation too, like `email composer`, making developers wasting many hours on things that have solution already.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `CREATE TABLE` will throw an exception if the table already exists.
 
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` query will create the table if it doesn't exist, otherwise simply ignores the command by throwing an exception. 
    If you want to create a table anyhow then you need to drop the existing table by using `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` before `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: That makes no sense. In all the examples I read until now, people use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` without using the instruction `DELETE TABLE IF EXISTS` (btw, it's `DROP TABLE` not `DELETE TABLE`). I already invested several hours in this and I'm starting to think the SQLite plugin is just plain buggy, at least its last version. The version I'm using now doesn't require an empty object `{}` at the end of the method call, not like all the examples I have read so far.